# Getting a count of a particular string

Tags: apache-pig

How can I count the number of occurances of a particular string,say 'Y' , for each individual row and do calculations on that count after that. For ex. how can I find the number of 'Y' for each 'FMID' and do calculations on that count for each FMID ?[Dataset Screenshot](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-saLCdU5kAhM/UshtiY1CD9I/AAAAAAAAARQ/0klzR1vREa4/w1044-h67-no/farmers+market.png)

Comment: I am not really aware of how to use pig but can suggest a SQL solution, maybe that gives an idea. How about you do something like `SELECT (SUM(IF(SFMNP=='Y',1,0))+SUM(IF(SNAP=='Y',1,0))+....+SUM(IF(Cheese=='Y',1,0))) FROM table_name`. This would give you the number of `Y` in each row

Comment: Show the code you have tried that is not working.

Comment: I couldn't think of anything that would work on it. I searched a lot on the net also but couldn't find anything. FOREACH..GENERATE can help but donot know how to add the number of 'Y' using it.

Comment: I also tried UDF.Here is my code

Comment: http://goo.gl/M6dJbJ

It is giving the following as output.
0
0
0
0
0
.
.
.
0
0

Answer (score 0):

You could use TOKENIZE built-in function which converts row into a BAG and than use nested filtering in the foreach to get a BAG that contains only word you are interested in, on which you can use COUNT. See [FOREACH description](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#foreach)
For example:

```
inpt = load '....' as (line : string);
row_bags = foreach inpt generate line, TOKENIZE(line) as word;
cnt = foreach row_bags {
   match_1 = filter word by 'Y';
   match_2 = filter word by 'X';
   generate line, COUNT(match_1) as count_1, COUNT(match_2) as count_2;
};
dump cnt;
```

Using some functions from DataFu library you could get count for each string in the BAG word.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way I can think of solving your problem:

```
define Transpose datafu.pig.util.TransposeTupleToBag();

data = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS 
       (fmid:int, field1:chararray, field2:chararray, 
                  field3:chararray, field4:chararray);

data2 = FOREACH data GENERATE fmid, Transpose($1..) as fields;

data2 = FOREACH data2 {
  y_fields = FILTER fields BY value == 'Y';
  GENERATE fmid, SIZE(y_fields) as y_cnt;
}
```

I'm not really certain about the data schema you're working with.  I'm going to assume you have a relation in Pig consisting of a sequence of tuples.  I'm also going to assume you have a lot of fields, making it a pain to reference each individually.

I'll walk through this example piece by piece to explain.  Without loss of generality, I will use this data below for my example:

```
data = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (fmid:int, field1:chararray, field2:chararray, field3:chararray, field4:chararray);
```

Now that we've loaded the data, we want to transpose each tuple to a bag, because once it is in a bag we can perform counts on the items within it more easily.  We'll use TransposeTupleToBag from the [DataFu](http://datafu.org) library:

```
define Transpose datafu.pig.util.TransposeTupleToBag();

data2 = FOREACH data GENERATE fmid, Transpose($1..) as fields;
```

Note that you need at least Pig 0.11 to use this UDF.  Note the use of $1.., which is known as a project-range expression in Pig.  If you have many fields this is really convenient.

If you were to dump data2 at this point you would get this:

```
(1000,{(field1,N),(field2,N),(field3,N),(field4,N)})
(2000,{(field1,N),(field2,Y),(field3,N),(field4,N)})
(3000,{(field1,Y),(field2,Y),(field3,N),(field4,N)})
(4000,{(field1,Y),(field2,Y),(field3,Y),(field4,Y)})
```

What we've done is taken the fields from the tuple after the 0th element (fmid), and tranposed these into a bag where each tuple has a key and value field.

Now that we have a bag we can do a simple filter and count:

```
data2 = FOREACH data2 {
  y_fields = FILTER fields BY value == 'Y';
  GENERATE fmid, SIZE(y_fields) as y_cnt;
}
```

Now if you dump data2 you get the expected counts reflecting the number of Y values in the tuple.

```
(1000,0)
(2000,1)
(3000,2)
(4000,4)
```

Here is the full source code for my example as a unit test, which you can put directly in the DataFu unit tests to try out:

```
/**
register $JAR_PATH

define Transpose datafu.pig.util.TransposeTupleToBag();

data = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (fmid:int, field1:chararray, field2:chararray, field3:chararray, field4:chararray);

data2 = FOREACH data GENERATE fmid, Transpose($1..) as fields;

dump data2;

data2 = FOREACH data2 {
  y_fields = FILTER fields BY value == 'Y';
  GENERATE fmid, SIZE(y_fields) as y_cnt;
}

dump data2;

STORE data2 INTO 'output';
 */
@Multiline
private String example;

@Test
public void example() throws Exception
{
  PigTest test = createPigTestFromString(example);

  writeLinesToFile("input", 
                   "1000,N,N,N,N",
                   "2000,N,Y,N,N",
                   "3000,Y,Y,N,N",
                   "4000,Y,Y,Y,Y");

  test.runScript();

  super.getLinesForAlias(test, "data2");
}
```

Comment: I downloaded the Datafu (datafu-1.0.0) and when I am opening it in eclipse,it is throwing a lot of errors (mainly import errors).Can you please clarify what are the libraries I should add in it.
Also, I am using Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.4.0 and datafu is tested against pig 0.11.1 version onwards. Can it be the problem ?

Comment: You are probably missing the Ivy plugin for eclipse.  Check the plugin installation instructions [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/download.cgi).  But you could also just download the JAR directory from [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.linkedin.datafu%22%20AND%20a%3A%22datafu%22) without downloading the source.